# ASP.Net Core storing and retrieving an entity against identity user

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I am building a Web API and have implemented registration and login. I have a model called **Task** which is as following:

```
public class User_Task
{
    [Key]
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public string What { get; set; }

    public string How_often { get; set; }
    public string How_important { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FeatureId")]
    public long? FeatureId { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }

    public User_Task()
    {

    }
}
```

It's repository:

```
public class User_TaskRepository : IUser_TaskRepository
{
    private readonly WebAPIDataContext _context;

    public User_TaskRepository(WebAPIDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    public IEnumerable<User_Task> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.User_Tasks.Include(task => task.Steps).ToList();
    }

    public void Add(User_Task item)
    {
        _context.User_Tasks.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public User_Task Find(long key)
    {
        return _context.User_Tasks.Include(task => task.Steps).FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaskId == key);
    }

    public void Remove(long key)
    {
        var entity = _context.User_Tasks.First(t => t.TaskId == key);
        _context.User_Tasks.Remove(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(User_Task item)
    {
        _context.User_Tasks.Update(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public interface IUser_TaskRepository
{
    void Add(User_Task item);
    IEnumerable<User_Task> GetAll();
    User_Task Find(long key);
    void Remove(long key);
    void Update(User_Task item);
}
```

And it's controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class User_TaskController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUser_TaskRepository _taskRepository;

    //Controller
    public User_TaskController(IUser_TaskRepository taskRepository)
    {
        _taskRepository = taskRepository;
    }

    //Get methods
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User_Task> GetAll()
    {
        return _taskRepository.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTask")]
    public IActionResult GetById(long id)
    {
        var item = _taskRepository.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }

    //Create
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] User_Task item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _taskRepository.Add(item);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetTask", new { id = item.TaskId }, item);
    }

    //Update
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Update(long id, [FromBody] User_Task item)
    {

        if (item == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var task = _taskRepository.Find(id);
        if (task == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        task.What = item.What;
        task.How_often = item.How_often;
        task.How_important = item.How_important;

        UpdateTaskSteps(item.Steps, task.Steps);

        _taskRepository.Update(task);
        return new NoContentResult();
    }

    private void UpdateTaskSteps(ICollection<Step> steps, ICollection<Step> taskSteps)
    {
        foreach (var step in steps)
        {
            Step taskStep = taskSteps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StepId == step.StepId);
            if (taskStep != null)
            {
                // Update
                taskStep.What = step.What;
            }
            else
            {
                // Create
                taskSteps.Add(new Step
                {
                    What = step.What,
                    TaskId = step.TaskId
                });
            }

        }

    }

    //Delete
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(long id)
    {
        var task = _taskRepository.Find(id);
        if (task == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _taskRepository.Remove(id);
        return new NoContentResult();
    }


}
```

Now I have **ApplicationUser** model as following:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Extended Properties
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {

    }
}
```

And yet another Stakeholder model:

```
public class Stakeholder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IdentityId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Identity { get; set; }  // navigation property

    public Stakeholder()
    {

    }

}
```

How can I make sure that each Task is created against the logged in user i.e. Stakeholder? I will have to update my Task model with a foreign key to Stakeholder? How can I do that, and how can update my controller methods so that I can send back Tasks belonging to the user/Stakeholder making the request?

**UPDATE: startup.cs**

```
 public class Startup
    {
        private const string SecretKey = "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH"; // todo: get this from somewhere secure
        private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<WebAPIDataContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection"), 
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Vision_backlog_backend"));
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();

            // jwt wire up
            // Get options from app settings
            var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

            // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
            services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
                options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
                options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            });


            services.AddScoped<IProfileRepository, ProfileRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUser_TaskRepository, User_TaskRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IFeatureRepository, FeatureRepository>();


            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            // api user claim policy
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
            });

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
                (o =>
                {
                    // configure identity options
                    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebAPIDataContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());

            services.AddAutoMapper();


            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            // global policy - assign here or on each controller
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");


            var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
            });


            app.UseMvc();

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've understood, you want each Stakeholder to have a list of User_Task.
I suggest you add a foreign key to your User_Task class which references the Stakeholder Id, then add navigation properties to your User_Task and Stakeholder classes.

The following should work:

**User_Task class:**

```
public class User_Task
{
    [Key]
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public string What { get; set; }

    public string How_often { get; set; }
    public string How_important { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FeatureId")]
    public long? FeatureId { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }

    // EF should detect a reference to another table if your property name follows the {className}{idName} format
    // so the ForeignKey attribute isn't really needed
    [ForeignKey("StakeholderId")]
    [Required]
    public int StakeholderId { get; set; }
    public Stakeholder Stakeholder { get; set; }

    public User_Task()
    {

    }
}
```

**Stakeholder class:**

```
public class Stakeholder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IdentityId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Identity { get; set; }

    // navigation property for User_Tasks
    public ICollection<User_Task> User_Tasks { get; set; }

    public Stakeholder()
    {

    }

}
```

For your **repository class**, you could have a method that returns all Tasks that belong to a certain Stakeholder based on the logged in user's Id:

```
public ICollection<User_Task> GetUserTasks(string userId){

    Stakeholder currentStakeholder = _context.Stakeholders
        .FirstOrDefault(sh => sh.IdentityId == userId);

    var userTasks = _context.User_Tasks
        .Where(task => task.StakeholderId == currentStakeholder.Id).ToList();

    return userTasks;
}
```

Now to get the logged in user's Id, you have to use the **UserManager class**, which should be injected into your DI Container by IdentityServer if you've set it up correctly. So you just have to add a UserManager to your controller's constructor.
The Controller class has a property called **"User"**, which you can pass to the **GetUserId()** method of the UserManager class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class User_TaskController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUser_TaskRepository _taskRepository;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    //Controller
    public User_TaskController(IUser_TaskRepository taskRepository, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _taskRepository = taskRepository;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    // The Authorize header means that this method cannot be accessed if the requester is not authenticated
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("current")]
    public IActionResult GetCurrentUserTasks()
    {
        string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
        var userTasks = _taskRepository.GetUserTasks(userId);

        return userTasks;
    }


}
```

**Some additional things to consider:**

- You might want to adopt RESTful style when it comes to your APIs. Consider making the logged in user access his own tasks through another controller that follows a pattern like: /Account/Tasks
- Since EF Core does not support Lazy Loading yet, you don't need to add the "virtual" keyword before navigation properties
- You can also setup foreign keys in your DbContext's OnModelCreating method as follows:

---

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<User_Task>().HasOne(t => t.Stakeholder).WithMany(sh => sh.User_Tasks).HasForeignKey(t => t.StakeholderId);

        }
```

### Update

Adding a Task to a specific user in your **repository class**:

```
public void Add(string userId, User_Task item)
    {
        Stakeholder currentStakeholder = _context.Stakeholders
            .FirstOrDefault(sh => sh.IdentityId == userId);
        item.StakeholderId = currentStakeholder.Id;
        _context.User_Tasks.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

You could also add a Task to a Stakeholder by calling "Add()" to a Stakeholder object's User_Tasks ICollection.
Another thing to keep in mind: You should probably use DTOs when dealing with input for creating your entities. Users shouldn't have the possibility of setting the primary keys of entries, unless that's something you want because of some use case.

Comment: Thanks Omar for such a nice detailed answer! It is going to help me a lot and whoever refers to this question. I just had to change return userTasks; in controller to return new ObjectResult(userTasks); otherwise it was giving me casting error. Also, putting OnModelCreating() method in DBContext makes my AccountController unreachable throwing 5oo internal server error and I was not able to create a new user, so I haven't added it. Could you also perhaps point out like GetCurrentUserTasks() how can I implement a method for creating task with specific userId?

Comment: You can create a task with a specific userId by adding it to the Task object and saving your changes.
I'll edit my previous answer to add an example and change the return type of the GetCurrentUserTasks() method.

I also wonder why you got a 500 error when adding the OnModelCreating() override. Any details on that?

Comment: The code you wrote in your update is part of Task repositor's create method right?

Comment: Yeah it was to give you a general idea of how it would work. I've edited the code snippet to show how your Add(User_Task item) method in your repository class would look like. In your controller you'd get the logged in user's ID, then you'd pass it along with the Task object to the repository's Add method

Comment: Thanks a lot Omar! It was really really helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome :) If you'd like I could share some helpful resources for you to get started with ASP.NET Core

Comment: Definitely! I am more interested in building APIs and had always used Django so far. This is the first time I am using ASP.Net Core and I find community support is far less as compared to Django or Angular.

Comment: There is only one problem with above solution and that is: string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User); returns email address and not a number. So I am now manually iterating over users with that email to get identityId and then over Stakeholders to find that identityId to get actual numeric id to insert into Task table!

Comment: You probably haven't setup ASP.NET Core Identity properly. What does your Startup class look like?

Comment: Alright so I've noticed you're using Jwt Authentication. When you call _userManager.GetUserId(User) with Jwt Authentication, you get the "sub" Claim returned, which should usually be the user ID. My guess is that in your JwtFactory class, you're setting the "sub" claim to the user's email instead of the ID.

Comment: Correct! But it's not a big issue as such. I am still grateful to your perfect answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145483/discussion-between-omar-beyhum-and-nitish).